# error when cout vector size minus a number bigger than the size ( vector.size()-n )

Tags: c++, vector, size

I have a vector a={1,2}, so a.size()=2;

I found that:

```
cout<<(a.size()-3);
```

will give me a weird number (e.g. 18446744073709551615).

why is it not -1?

if I do:

```
cout<<(a.size-2);
```

or

```
int s = a.size-3;
cout<<s;
```

everything is normal (-1).

Answer (score 1):

`size()` returns a `size_t`, which is an unsigned type. When performing a calculation that's supposed to return a negative number, it underflows, and you get the huge value you observed. When you explicitly assign the result to a (signed) int, you treat the result as a signed number, and get the expected result of `-1`.

Comment: *Side note*: [`std::vector<T>::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) *usually* has the return type `size_t` but not *always*. The actual type of `std::vector<T>::size()` is `std::vector<T>::size_type` which is an alias to the `size_type` member type of the allocator used by the `std::vector` (which is usually the default allocator, i.e., [`std::allocator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator), where `std::allocator<T>::size_type` is `size_t`.) In case some other allocator is used, the return type of `std::vector<T>::size()` may change.